# Example of an integral domain with a non-principal prime ideal of height one

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Is there an integral domain $R$ with a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of
>   height $1$ which is not a principal ideal?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with Dedekind domains which are not principal ideal domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157461/why-is-2-1-sqrt-5-not-principal) that the ideal $\mathfrak p=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not principal. This is a maximal ideal of height one.

Comment: I am confused: $(0)$ a prime ideal in this ring since it is a domain. There is a chain $(0)\subsetneq (2)\subsetneq \mathfrak{p}$ of ideals. Your answer implies that $(2)$ is not a prime ideal which means that $2$ is not a prime element in this ring. Is this true?

Comment: @jeffrey Please read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77012/irreducible-but-not-prime-in-mathbbz-sqrt-5).